# Android: Refresh the previous fragment data when pressed backbutton

Tags: android, performance

I've got 2 Fragments, Fragment A and Fragment B. I added Fragment B over Fragment A, by using `FragmentTransaction().add`, which means Fragment A is underlying Fragment B. Is there a way to change the data in Fragment A after I did something on Fragment B and pressed the **Back** button from Fragment B? I wish to have a generic way to notify the Fragment A. Because it may be another Fragment being overlaid. I tried using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` - it works fine for refreshing the previous page.

Comment: Use some callback in fragment A that you reference in fragment B on creation

Comment: thannks for replied, can u give me some link or example.. how to implement callback? i did see from android documentation .. but still not understanding.. please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just overwrite `onBackPressed()` in your activity and your fragment and do your required calls there.

More to callbacks / communication with other fragments can be found here:

[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    public void updateMyself(String updateValue){
        Log.v("update", "weeee Fragment B updated me with" + updateValue);
    }
}

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    public Interface FragmentBCallBackInterface {
        public void update(String updateValue);
    }

    private FragmentBCallBackInterface mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mCallback = (FragmentBCallBackInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentBCallBackInterface");
        }
        //As an example we do an update here - normally you wouln't call the method until your user performs an onclick or something 
        letsUpateTheOtherFragment();
    }

    private void letsUpateTheOtherFragment(){
        mCallback.update("This is an update!);
    }
}


public class MyActivity extends Activity implements FragmentInterfaceB {

    @Override
    public void update(String updateValue){
          FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (fragmentA != null) {
            fragmentA.updateMyself(updateValue);
        } else {
            //replace the fragment... bla bla check example for this code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for replied. ya i did see the link u mentioned above before and also think this solution may help me, but i am new to android. so need sometime to understand it. do u have any good example about this and easy for me to understand?

Comment: Ya thanks,it help me alot. But have to find out which is previous fragment of Fragment B. Because i have multiple fragment calling same fragment B. Thanks ya!